# What is the meaning of 'as much as' in "Kevin dislikes apples as much as bananas."?

Tags: phrase-meaning, phrase-usage

> Kevin dislikes apples **as much as** bananas.

Does the statement suggest that Kevin has an **equal** dislike for apples and bananas?

Answer (score 3):

"As much as" implies an equal feeling.  Note that there's a syntactic ambiguity built into this construction, depending on the ellipsis involved.  Let's take the example

> Kevin dislikes apples as much as Sarah.

This could mean that

> Kevin dislikes apples as much as he dislikes Sarah

or that

> Kevin dislikes apples as much as Sarah dislikes apples.

If we refer to Sarah by pronoun, we can resolve the ambiguity because the first construct requires "as much as her" and the second requires "as much as she."

In your example, the semantics allow only for the first construct because bananas can't like or dislike anything.  Thus Kevin treats both apples and bananas with equal distaste.

Comment: All true, but TMI. Your first sentence, plus an apt citation, would have sufficed.